# Color Problem in Render

Tags: export, color, color-management, filmic-blender

I've searched for countless hours for a fix to this problem.

The thing is:

1- I have a design with #F8F7FD on the Background and I'll need to put some 3D on top of that. [image: Design Hex code]

2- In blender, I have a scene and the floor material needs to be exactly on the same hex code to seamlessly blend in the design.
3- So in the Material, I've used the #F8F7FD hex and removed the specular and maxed out the roughness.
4- Using Filmic automatically makes the scene darker, the usage of a hdri affects the color on the floor and messes up the exact color that I need. The standard color management makes the color brighter. Using the #F8F7FD as the BG color lightens up the whole scene and messes up the floor texture.[image: Render in the design]

Can someone help me on this?? Basically I just need to render in the exact color on the floor to seamlessly blend in the design.

P.S. Also tried using the floor as a shadow catcher but for some reason this happens to the shadows...[image: Messed shadows with shadowcatcher]

Comment: Have you tried using just the diffuse instead of principled BSDF ?

Comment: That's not really a problem it's just how path tracing works, cycles just tries to mimic real world physics. If you'd take a bright light and pointing it onto any colored (slightly reflecting) surface it won't be the same color as before. I'd suggest use cryptomattes and try to match the color in comp.

Comment: Hello and Welcome. Do you really need to render a Background? because you could render with transparent background and the put tha render on top of your design

Comment: Hey Emir, I tried and like you see in the image, the shadows get messed up for some reason

Comment: I need the geometry to be on a "floor with shadows casted on it" and integrated into the exact color on the design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your settings are, but with transparency should work, basically you need a plane with shadow catcher ON and transparency under render settings

[image]

Then you need to go to the compositing tab and use "Alpha over" node to connect your background image to your render.
Here is an example with the image background that you posted

[image]

Comment: Yeah I did that with the transparency and the shadow catcher but for some reason, in the render, the shadows gain noise and other shadows appear ( like in the picture above that ie uploaded ). I kinda solved it by using a hdri and a shadowcatcher and changing the color management to Standard, now I just have to figure how to tone down the shadows.